# GWT CellTable SelectionModel can not deselect item after editing

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, celltable, selectionmodel

Hello I have a **Contact** class with informations which i show in a **CellTable**.
The **CellTable** has a **DataListProvider**, **MultiSelectionModel** and **KeyProvider**
which checks the **id** of the **Contact**.

DataListProvider and CellTable have the same KeyProvider.

if i only *select/deselect* the items in the **CellTable** and show them in a *TextBox* ists working fine. But the when i change the value of the Contact item in the TextBox(Contact instance) and try to *deselect* the item the selectionmodel says its still selected?

I tried with *clear()* but its still selected!

**GWT 2.5 / FireFox**

```java
ProvidesKey<Contact> keyProvider = new ProvidesKey<Contact>(){
    @Override
    public Object getKey(Contact item) {
        return item.getIdContact();
    }
};


public MyCellTable(boolean canLoad, Integer pagesize, ProvidesKey<T> keyProvider) {
    super(-1, resource, keyProvider);

    selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<T>();
    selectionModel .addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
            selectionChange();
        }
    });

    dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<T>(keyProvider);
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(this);
}
```

in the selection event i call

```java
protected void selectionChange(){
    Contact c = grid.getGrid().getSelectedItem();
    if(c != null){
        cpForm.enable();
        cpForm.clear();
        form.bind(c); // Formular which updates the selected instance 
        cpForm.add(form);
    }else{
        cpForm.disable(noseletionText);
    }
}
```

i have no *ValueUpdater*

when i select an item i generate a formular and if i change something i call:

```java
@Override
public void save() {
    super.save();
    ContactServiceStore.get().updateContact(manager.getBean(),
            new MyAsyncCallback<Void>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                    onchange();
                }

            });
}
```

i if call the method without changes on the contact its still working and i can deselect but when i change the name or something else i cant select other items or deselect the current item!

Comment: Can you put some code in the question? Perhaps the `ValueUpdater` implementation as well as the `KeyProvider` for the `DataListProvider` and `MultiSelectionModel`.

Comment: put a breakpoint in your `KeyProvider` and make sure it is really called. Could it be that the an exception is thrown when you save the instance ? If the exception is not caught it might break the execution of the de-selection code (check Chrome Developer Tools console)

Comment: i tried with breakpoints the idContact value in datalistprovider and celltable had the same value and the rpc calls onSuccess because i get in the breakPoint in onChange(); (i tried there to call clear() when i updated the contact but the old item was still selected???)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually using your `ProvidesKeys` in your `MultiSelectionModel`. You need to create your `MultiSelectionModel` like so:

```
MultiSelectionModel<T> selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<T>(keyProvider);
```

If you don't supply the `MultiSelectionModel` with a `ProvidesKey` it will use the actual object as a key.

Make sure you also add the `MultiSelectionModel` to the table:

```
cellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
```

The reason `selectionModel.clear()` wasn't working was because `selectionModel` was not set to the table.